# Simulate click on one element with JS or Jquery when clicking a different element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want one item to be clicked when I click on a different one, but I keep seeing these complicated answers that, frankly, don't make any sense. I feel like it should be easy as this, but this doesn't work.

```
<div class="myElement" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
<a href="https://example.com" class="myElement2"></a>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('myElement2').click();
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName() method returns an array

Comment: Why not fire both `myElement` and `myElement2` functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

There're some points you need to know:

1. getElementsByClassName returns an array
2. there have to be something in the `<div>`, otherwise it's height is 0px, so you have no where to click

try this one:

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('myElement2')) {
        e.click();
    }
}
</script>

<div class="myElement" onclick="myFunction()">
    hello
</div>
<a href="https://example.com" class="myElement2"></a>
```